# Why is pg_stat_activity.query_start null for almost all queries?

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-activity

Why is pg_stat_activity.query_start null for almost all queries?  What is the meaning of a NULL query_start field?

Comment: If you can see results once, then you have permissions! We need more depth to this question - what problem are you having and trying to solve?

Comment: @Vérace I want to see the long running queries, but the query_start fields are almost all null.  Do you know under which conditions they are null?

Comment: So, show us what you are doing! You run `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity.query_start;` - yes? And you get results? Show them to us - in the form of text - not screenshots. I'm afraid that I can't answer your question about the conditions under which they are null - what does the documentation (normally very good) say?

Comment: I do select * from pg_stat_activity and I see query_start is almost always null...

Comment: Yes, I understand, but as I said, what does the documentation say?

Comment: The documentation does not answer my question, at least not that I saw.  That's why I asked here...

Comment: Well then maybe you should rephrase your question by asking "What is the  meaning of a NULL start field in pg_...."? I'm afraid that I don't know!

Answer (score 2):

The only meaning I know of for a NULL query_start field is that no query has ever been started on that connection.

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot more helpful than Verace pretending it's confusing and putting it on hold because he doesn't know the answer.